# Emgu SetCaptureProperty CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES does not work as expected

Tags: emgucv

```
        m_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameID);
        double cap = m_capture.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
```

I am using Emgu 2.3 (x64) and the set capture property as above works bizarrely. For instance in the above I am setting frameID = 500 and check the capture property back and it is set to returns value of 3325.

Anything I am doing wrong?